# How to avoid sum-issues in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, sum, report, stimulsoft

I use 'Stimulsoft Reports.Net' to calculate a total price based on multiple items with different prices, ammount and tax-rates. This is my code:

```
{
    Sum
    (
        DataBandTax,
        (
            Positions.UnitPrice *
            Positions.Amount *
            (
                Positions.Article.TaxRate +
                100
            )
        ) /
        100
    )
}
```

Positions is a Bussines-Object, each object of Positions has exactly one Article.
While Positions.UnitPrice and Positions.Amount are multiplied correctly, Stimulsoft uses for every calculation the same Positions.Article.TaxRate, instead the TaxRate which fits to its Position. For example:

```
Position | UnitPrice | Amount | TaxRate
1        |    100    |    3   |    5
2        |     50    |   10   |   10
3        |     20    |    5   |    3
```

So the calculation should be:

```
  ((100 * 3 * (5 + 100)) / 100)
+ ((50 * 10 * (10 + 100)) / 100)
+ ((20 * 5 * (3 + 100)) / 100)
= 315 + 550 + 103
= 968
```

Instead stimulsoft calculates this: (In this example it uses only the TaxRate of Position 1)

```
  ((100 * 3) + (50 * 10) + (20 * 5)) 
* (1+(5/100))
= (300 + 200 + 100) * 1.05
= 600 * 1.05
= 630
```

How do I stop stimulsoft from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue, by placing the TaxRate inside Positions (instead of Positions.Article). Seems like Stimulsoft has a problem when a sum includes object-values and sub-object-values at the same time.

```
{
    Sum
    (
        DataBandTax,
        (
            Positions.UnitPrice *
            Positions.Amount *
            (
                Positions.TaxRate +
                100
            )
        ) /
        100
    )
}
```